# Send message to a Webhook when I post a video

Tags: youtube-api

I have a community group and want make it send a message when I post a video, and to do it I'm trying use webhook, is possible I make it works with youtube?

Comment: Is this a Webhook + Youtube Integration?

Comment: The intended is make a webhook send a message when I post a video. So I think that is.